# Search keyword in array to get the value - php

Tags: php, arrays, search, blob

Basically i am reading BLOB data from my table.

```
$sql = "SELECT blob_data as datajson FROM tablename";
$res=$obj->_executeQuery($sql);
$res=$obj->getAll($res);
```

This will give me data inside my BLOB and i have converted to array.

```
for($y=0;$y<count($res);$y++)                           
{
    $decode = json_decode($res[$y]['datajson']);
    if(!empty($decode))
    {
        foreach($decode as $name => $value)  
        {               
            print_r($value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return(0);
    }   
}
```

Now my `print_r($value);` will give me

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => dinner
    [value] => Dinner~360
)
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => fullday
    [value] => Full Day~805
)
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => expenseamount
    [value] => Expense Amount~805
)
```

Now i need to search **expenseamount** by *name* and should get its value. Here i should get

`Expense Amount~805`.

And I cannot do **foreach($decode[2] as $name => $value)** from its position, as the position will change everytime. I am unable to search by name. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
foreach($decode as $name => $value)  
    {               
        if($value->name =="expenseamount") {
              echo $value->value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.